# Open xml a php page

Tags: php, xml

Good, again I ask your help, I have a xml file (http://radiojoven.6te.net/AirPlayHistory.xml) with several songs and I just wanted to take the song "I Need Your Love" from "SHAGGY "but I using a code I found here can not, appears all the songs. Could help me solve the problem?

```js
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://radiojoven.6te.net/AirPlayHistory.xml");
foreach($xml->Song as $item)
   echo $item->Artist['name'] . " - " . $item['title'] ."<br>";
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question. So what you are looking for is a single song?

Comment: @complex857 Yes, I just wanted the music I NEED YOUR LOVE / SHAGGY, through the echo php if you can help me was very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for a conditional control structures, namely [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) (I'm sorry if I'm something you already know). So inside your loop you can go:

```
foreach($xml->Song as $item) {
   if ($item->Artist['name'] == 'SHAGGY' && $item['title'] == 'I NEED YOUR LOVE') {
       echo $item->Artist['name'] . " - " . $item['title'] ."<br>";
    }
}
```

(Sorry for the unrealistic example, you probably get the derails for the conditionals in variables).

There are other ways to query and filter things specific to XML documents, namely [xpath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) that use can use as well.

Comment: Help yourself and, just one more question how do I remove the xml information (Info StartTime =) in php echo?

Comment: I don't think you have anything to remove, in the example they aren't there. The `StartTime=".."` and others like that are called attributes. If you want to have their value you can get it with: `$item->Info->attributes()['StartTime']` and the like.